# Linear system $Ax=b$ is inconsistent implies $\det(A)=0$

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

Consider a matrix equation $Ax=b$.

If $\det(A)=0$, it follows that the equation has a non-unique solution or it does not have solutions at all.

I have proven that if the rows/columns of $A$ are linearly dependent, then $\det(A)=0$ and $Ax=0$ does not have a unique solution. Therefore the original equation $Ax=b$ does not have a unique solution.

However what I haven't been able to prove is that if the system of linear equations is inconsistent, then the determinant is zero. If the system is inconsistent, **does it always imply that row operations on the matrix A lead to a zero row**?

Comment: If there is no solution, it follows that the matrix is not invertible. Then it is not full rank. Then the columns are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 3):

Let's prove the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition#Formal_definition). If $\det A\ne0$, $A^{-1}$ exists, so $Ax=b$ has exactly one solution, $x=A^{-1}b$, i.e. is not inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

If they wouldn't, then Elementary Row Operations would bring it to its [Reduced Row Echelon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) Form which would have no zero rows. This can only happen if the RRE form is in fact $I_n$. This implies that $A$ is invertible so $\mathrm{det}(A) \neq 0$.